# Howto relation of data in Python (pickle datas)?

Tags: python, pickle, relation

I'm new in python environment,
so I created an example small project to try this:

1. creating of phone brand and save into brands.pkl
   text fields: "brand name"
2. creating of phone model with selecting a brand from previous created brand via dropdown
   and save into models.pkl
   text fields: phone name
   dropdown: brand from created.

But I haven't found a solution to relation it (in sql I can use foreign key by id).

Thank you.

Here is my example code:

```
def phones(self):

    saved_phones= util.load_phones()

    return json.dumps(saved_phones)

@cherrypy.expose
def new_brands(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        saved_brands = util.load_brands()

        brand = {'name': kwargs['brand_name']}

        try:
            brand['id'] = saved_brands[-1]['id'] + 1
        except IndexError:
            brand['id'] = 1

        saved_brands.append(brand)
        util.save_brands(saved_brands)

        return json.dumps(brand)
    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error': str(e)})


@cherrypy.expose
def new_phones(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        saved_phones = util.load_phones()

        phone = {'model': kwargs['phone_model']}

        try:
            phone['id'] = saved_module[-1]['id'] + 1
        except IndexError:
            phone['id'] = 1

        saved_phones.append(phone)
        util.save_phones(saved_phones)

        return json.dumps(phone)
    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error': str(e)})


def save_phones(phones):
    pickle.dump(phones, open('phones.pkl', 'wb'))


def load_phones():
    try:
        saved_phones = pickle.load(open('phones.pkl', 'rb'))
    except IOError:
        saved_phones = []

    return saved_phones

def get_modul(phones, phone_id):
    for phone in phones:
        if phone['id'] == phone_id:
            return phone
        # if
    # for

    return None


def save_brands(brands):
    pickle.dump(brands, open('brands.pkl', 'wb'))


def load_brands():
    try:
        saved_brands = pickle.load(open('brands.pkl', 'rb'))
    except IOError:
        saved_brands = []

    return saved_brands

def get_modul(brands, brand_id):
    for brand in brands:
        if brand['id'] == brand_id:
            return brand
        # if
    # for

    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

pickle might be a lousy fit for the problem you seem to be trying to solve.  pickle makes some sense when you want to persist or transmit a bundle of related objects all in one shot.

maybe you really do want a sql database?  `sqlite3` bindings are provided with python out of the box, and you can transition to a more robust database when the time comes with minimal effort.

Comment: "must solve it via python"; can you elaborate on that a bit?  `sqlite3` should be available everywhere python is.  Is this not available for some reason?

Comment: if i use sqlite3, then is the data stored in sql-database-file,
but not in pickle file